# How do I insert bulk data into Membase Server 1.6 using some Client Tool

Tags: c#, java, .net, client-server, membase

I am using **Membase Server 1.6.5-win64**. I need to store **400 Million** rows from database. Right now, I have a C#.Net windows App which is executing parallel tasks to write to server. What are my best options to bulk load data as quickly as possible into Membase Server using any existing Tools. Can I use some csv/other format which can just read data and store in membase key value pair? Please Suggest.

My values for the keys are in string format. I have a machine with **8 Core Processor** & **12GB RAM**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Membase 1.6.5 uses sqlite3.7 to persist data, you can convert your database files to sqlite db files. After that, you can use mbrestore tool from membase to load data into membase.